# To upload a file using richfaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

In RichFaces, inorder to upload a file I used `rich:fileUpload`. By using `rich:fileUpload` Add, Upload and Clear All buttons are automatically generating in the  richfaces livedemo example but for me Add, Upload and Clear All are appearing as text in my browser where should I change so that Add,upload and clearAll can be clickable. Do I have to change any settings in `web.xml` / `pom.xml` file.

I am using RichFaces 4 and JSF 2.

This is my web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>Sample RichFaces 4 Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>#{skinBean.skin}</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
    <param-value>1000000000</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ecss</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Hi, i am getting those add and update buttons now correctly by simply providing h:head and h:body tags  but i am getting this exception javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException and files are not being uploaded as shown in the example provided in the link "[FileUpload example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf)".Can anyone plz help me out from this issue

This is my xhtml page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">



<ui:composition>
 <h:head>
 <h:outputStylesheet>
    .top {
    vertical-align: top;
    }
.info {
    height: 202px;
    overflow: auto;
    }
</h:outputStylesheet>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="top,top">
        <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
            ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5">
            <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" />
        </rich:fileUpload>
        <h:panelGrid id="info" layout="block">
            <rich:panel bodyClass="info">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Uploaded Files Info" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="No files currently uploaded" rendered="#{fileUploadBean.size==0}" />
                <rich:dataGrid columns="1" value="#{fileUploadBean.files}" var="file" rowKeyVar="row">
                    <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" createContent="#{fileUploadBean.paint}"
                                value="#{row}" style="width:100px; height:100px;" cacheable="false">
                                <f:param value="#{fileUploadBean.timeStamp}" name="time" />
                            </a4j:mediaOutput>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="File Name:" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{file.name}" />
                                <h:outputText value="File Length(bytes):" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{file.length}" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:panel>
                </rich:dataGrid>
            </rich:panel>
            <br/>
            <a4j:commandButton action="#{fileUploadBean.clearUploadData}" render="info, upload" value="Clear Uploaded Data"
                rendered="#{fileUploadBean.size>0}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

This is my FileUploadBean Class

```
package com.acc.upload;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.acc.fileupload.utils.FileUploadEvent;
import com.acc.fileupload.utils.UploadedFile;


@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadBean")
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadBean{

private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
private int uploadsAvailable = 5;
private boolean autoUpload = false;
private boolean useFlash = true;


public int getSize() {
    if (getFiles().size()>0){
        return getFiles().size();
    }else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public FileUploadBean() {
}

public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
    stream.write(getFiles().get((Integer)object).getData());
}
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception{
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    File file = new File();
    file.setLength(item.getData().length);
    file.setName(item.getName());
    file.setData(item.getData());
    files.add(file);
    uploadsAvailable--;
}  

public String clearUploadData() {
    files.clear();
    setUploadsAvailable(5);
    return null;
}

public long getTimeStamp(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(ArrayList<File> files) { 
    this.files = files;
}

public int getUploadsAvailable() {
    return uploadsAvailable;
}

public void setUploadsAvailable(int uploadsAvailable) {
    this.uploadsAvailable = uploadsAvailable;
}

public boolean isAutoUpload() {
    return autoUpload;
}

public void setAutoUpload(boolean autoUpload) {
    this.autoUpload = autoUpload;
}

public boolean isUseFlash() {
    return useFlash;
}

public void setUseFlash(boolean useFlash) {
    this.useFlash = useFlash;
}

}
```

File Class

```
package com.acc.upload;

public class File {

private String Name;
private String mime;
private long length;
private byte[] data;
public byte[] getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(byte[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
    int extDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if(extDot > 0){
        String extension = name.substring(extDot +1);
        if("png".equals(extension)){
            mime="image/png";
        }else {
            mime = "img/unknown";
        }
    }
}
public long getLength() {
    return length;
}
public void setLength(long length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public String getMime(){
    return mime;
}
}
```

Thanks a lot.Now that error is gone for me .
 I set the createTemp files to true in web.xml but i am unable to find the uploaded file in the temp folder in my local system.And also is it possible to store the uploaded file to a desired location in our local system by changing any settings in web.xml file ?
 Please help in these two issues.

Comment: What Richfaces version/JSF version and where is your web.xml?

Comment: Can you post your view code (rich:fileUpload) and your bean code related to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your buttons icons problem, I'm pretty sure you don't manage yourself the **skin** of RichFaces, so you can remove this from your `web.xml` :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>#{skinBean.skin}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

RichFaces will now use the default skin option.

According to your comment, you where missing h:head which is mandatory in order to include necessary resources CSS and JavaScript for RichFaces.

Moreover, your last problem is related to your imports that are bad :

```
import com.acc.fileupload.utils.FileUploadEvent;
import com.acc.fileupload.utils.UploadedFile;
```

should be replaced for :

```
import org.richfaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.richfaces.model.UploadedFile;
```

**Other info :**

The example you are based on is from **RichFaces 3.3.3** (this is shown in the footer). Double check your view code with [this](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload) example for **RichFaces 4.3.2**.

Comment: @Padmini You should update your question with these informations.

Comment: @Padmini updated answer, should work now, I've tested with your code and I only changed your imports to make it work.

Comment: @Padmini so the file get uploaded?

Comment: yes file is getting uploaded.But my requirement is to store the uploaded file in the local system.Could u plz help me how to do thiz

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem you should mark as answered and post this as a new question since it is a new one.

Comment: @Padmini Upload folder is related to your servlet container (Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc). Your files will by default be under `<tomcat-root>/temp` in the case you are using Tomcat. This folder setting is related to the servlet container.

Comment: I am using Tomcat I had already checked in the Tomcat temp folder i did n't find the uploaded files there.

Comment: @Padmini I've tested by myself and RichFaces doesn't upload at all when createTempFile is set to true, will do further investigation tomorrow.

Comment: Did u find any solution for my problem

Comment: @Padmini sorry tried but not find any solution. I'm still not using createTempFile since about 2 years. I remember had problems with that (in RichFaces 3.X) and can't make it work again (RichFaces 4.X).

Answer (score 0):

I also get this problem with richface 4.0.0 and spring 4. When upload the file I alway get this error message "Request prolog cannot be read".

And I solved this problem by: set multipart resolever to 
 instead of CommonsMultipartResolver 
for DispatcherServlet. Because the CommonsMultipartResolver of spring is not consistent with richface 4.0.0

Hope this help!